# CompareValidator asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, comparevalidator

I inserted a comaper validator in my page linked with a text box to just get numbers as input.

Here's the code,

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ContactNumber" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Input Only Numbers" SetFocusOnError="True" />
```

But when I input number like *xxxx-xxxxxxx* (i.e with a - in between) and then change the texbox, The error message just appears for a blink of an eye and vanishes.

Can anyone help in making it stay?
Or suggest any other way to just get numbers 0-9 input.

P.S: I have already applied 
**onkeypress="if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;"**
on my textbox, but the problem occurred when client copy pasted the number with - in between.

Help guys!

Comment: When a validator is not functioning properly, it usually means there is some other javascript code interfering. I tried to reproduce the problem but couldn't. The error message is contained in a `span` element, maybe that gives you a clue?

Comment: Remove onkeypress and see if the validator is working without it.